# Pyscripter - ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application

Tags: pyscripter

I am new to Pyscripter and found it interesting but getting the below error. lumberjack is an internal framework to work with.

```
>>> import lumberjack 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Perforce\svasudevan\HPro\lumberjack\__init__.py", line 1, in <module> import analysis
File "C:\Perforce\svasudevan\HPro\lumberjack\analysis.py", line 11, in <module> import scipy.signal
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scipy\signal\__init__.py", line 227, in <module> from . import sigtools
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I am sure that nothing wrong with the code above as I tried with Enthought Canopy and it works fine, since Pyscripter has more options to do with, I am using it but getting the above error.

FYI, all the modules like Numpy, Matplotlib, Scipy and Pyaudio has been imported successfully.

Could you please let me know the pre requisites to be done to correct this error. I think there is some problem with the env variables.

Thanks
Shobith

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that the version of Python that PyScripter is running is different than the one you get in EPD/Canopy (Python is compiled C code, so the version matters).  [There's another question about controlling the version of Python used with PyScripter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17155392/how-to-change-the-version-of-python-that-pyscripter-uses).

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, not exactly like yours but with a similar error, but going to the Run menu, then Python engine, then switching to remote from internal. I had noticed that I could import the module in IDLE but not PyScripter.